# Display rectangle size automatically

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

Is it possible to create a diagram in one of the adobe products, whereby next to each shape there is a label displaying the size of the shape. for example if i draw a 100x500 box it displays this number automatically and it changes when i re-size the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three applications can be scripted to do this. It's not a "built in" function that you can access through the UI.

Comment: Example / Citation requested.